# My registration view is not populating the user table in Django

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to do my login and register on the sane template, but have been having issues with it. please i need some help. Below are my codes:

views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('home')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rform = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if rform.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user()
            user.username = rform.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(rform.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.first_name = rform.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = rform.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = rform.cleaned_data['email']
            user.gender = rform.cleaned_data['gender']
            user.save()
            loggedin_user = authenticate(email = rform.cleaned_data['email'],
                                          password = rform.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user is not None:
                login(request, loggedin_user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return render(request, 'accounts/access.html', {'rform': RegistrationForm()})
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/access.html', {'rform': RegistrationForm()})
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'accounts/access.html', {'rform':form})


def login_now(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username = form.cleaned_data['email'], password = password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return render(request, 'accounts/access.html', {'form': AuthenticationForm(),      'rform':RegistrationForm(), 'next':reverse_lazy('home')})
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/access.html', {'form': AuthenticationForm(), 'rform':RegistrationForm(), 'next':reverse_lazy('home')})
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/access.html', {'form': AuthenticationForm(), 'rform':RegistrationForm(), 'next':reverse_lazy('home')})
```

forms.py:

```
CHOICES = [
('Male', "Male"),
('Female', "Female"),
]

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=25, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=25, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password Confirm'}), label=("Re-type Password"))
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'placeholder': 'Gender'}))

    class Meta:
        model = ('User',)

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.get(email=data):
            raise forms.ValidationError('A user with this email already exist. You may recover the password with a password reset')
        return data

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        if password1 and password and password1 != password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
            code='password_mismatch',
        )
        return password
```

access.html:

```
<div id = 'signup'>
        <form id="post-form" action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h3>REGISTER</h3>
            <div>
                {%for field in rform%}
                <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                    {{field.label_tag}}<br/> {{field}}
                    {%if field.errors%} <br/>{{field.errors}} {%endif%}
                </div>
                {%endfor%}
            </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class='sub' id='register'/>
    </div>
    <div id='login'>
    {% if form.errors %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors}}
        {% endif %}
        <form action='{% url 'login' %}' method='post' id ='signIn'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h3>SIGN IN</h3>
            <p><label>Email:</label><br/>
            {{ rform.email }}
            {{ rform.email.errors }}</p>
            <p><label>Password:</label><br/>
            {{ rform.password }}
            {{ rform.password.errors }}</p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="login" id='submit' class='sub' /><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'home' %}" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

I try to register with the above and all i always get, is a redirection, please i need help.
Thanks in advance.

Please note, i extended the user profile that's why i have the gender in my registration form.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not comparing the right parameters

```
loggedin_user = authenticate(email = rform.cleaned_data['email'],
                                      password = rform.cleaned_data['password'])
if user is not None:
    login(request, loggedin_user)
    return redirect('home')
```

You are checking an None variable, not the one returned by the authenticate ! `if loggedin_user is not None` is the correct check.

Check the example on the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login).

You need to send the validated form `rform` so you can show the feedback (errors) to the user, you are sending a new form after the validation `RegistrationForm()`!

Also try to identify the source of the problem, you are posting your hole code but you don't know where the problem comes from, at least do some debugging ;) !

Comment: Thanks for the observation and correction, but it's still not registering my users on my database